# ora2pg SDO_Geometry to st_geometry

Tags: postgis, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial, sdo-geometry

I am trying to migrate my database (Oracle) to postgres using ora2pg (v.23.1).
Unfortunately the script converts our SDO_Geometry datatype into

```
shape geometry(GEOMETRY,32632)
```

instead of

```
shape st_point ...
```

Is there a way to force ora2pg to convert SDO_Geometries to ST_Geometries?

Comment: Hi Ricckli ! Have you looked in the `TYPE SECTION` and `SPATIAL SECTION` in the ora2pg.conf file ?

Comment: I've tried this but still only geometry appears:
DATA_TYPE SDO_GEOMETRY:ST_GEOMETRY, VARCHAR2:varchar

Comment: As it is a SDE geoDB, maybe ora2pg doesn't know this type, so idk how to solve it. Maybe ask on the ora2pg Github repo.